# incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int[]

Tags: java

I am making a java program that prints the even and odd numbers of an array. This is my even code that returns the evens variable and prints the evens in the runner case.

```
public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array)
    {  
        String evens;

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]%2==0)
            {
                 evens = (array[i]+" ");
            }
        }
        return evens;   
    }
```

But when I compile, it says that the evens variable cannot be converted to int[]. I get that String or int shouldn't be used to define evens but I do not know how else I can return array[i]+" ".This is so difficult for me.

Comment: While adding integers to string, use Integer.toString() method to convert integer to string. Ex: evens += Integer.toString(array[i]) + " ";

Comment: There are two issues with your code. 1. you returning `String` where your method expects `int[]` 2. If you fix the return type to `String` you will get `Variable 'evens' might not have been initialized` error since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit 1: Using `Scanner` & using temporary `ArrayList` to make `int[]` compact

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int[] evens = getAllEvens1(arr);
        for (int i : evens) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] getAllEvens1(int[] array) {
        int[] temp = new int[array.length]; // if all of array are `even`..
        Arrays.fill(temp, -1); //or any flag.. to indicate it's unnecessary

        int j = 0;
        for (int i : array) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                temp[j++] = i;
            }
        }

        int[] ret = new int[j];
        j = 0;
        for (int i : temp) {
            if (i != -1) {
                ret[j++] = i;
            }
        }
        return ret;

    }

    public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();

        for (int i : array) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                temp.add(i);
            }
        }
        return temp.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
}
```

There are several problems in your code..
First you're trying to return `String` whereas your function return type is `int[]`
Secondly, you're assigning only current even number to the `String` which hasn't even initialized yet..

Fix:

```
 public static String getAllEvens(int[] array) {
        StringBuilder evens = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                evens.append(array[i]).append(" ");
            }
        }
        return evens.toString();
    }
```

Or by using `String` instead of `StringBuilder`:

```
  public static String getAllEvens(int[] array) {
        String ret = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                ret += array[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: @Sean, do you want to return int[] or String? please paste the codewhere you are calling this method

Comment: I want to return int[]. I want to call this method in the runner case, with the arrays from the scanner, but I haven't created the test cases yet, and I do not know how to. This should be the output of the method: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]

Comment: i have posted an answer, please check.

Comment: @Sean `Scanner` used and with the help of ArrayList we can make our `int[]` compact. Of course it can be done without `ArrayList` that case we need to use a flag `-1` or whatever and another temp `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

please change the return type of the method.
your returning String but method return type is int Array. That is the issue you're unable to compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could do some thing like this:

FYI: I have not tested this but should be ok.

```
public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array) {

int[] tmp = new int[array.length];
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
          tmp[even_count++] = array[i];
       }
   }

return tmp;
}
```